# Login failure with Rails 5.1.2 and Devise 4.3.0 Completed 401 Unauthorized (user verified)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am creating up a basic Devise/Rails authorization set up and can not login a user with known/verified email/password values.  As far as I can tell nothing out of the ordinary going on here.  Signin params show correct data being passed to the server:

> Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-07-08 14:34:45 -0400
>   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Fa7u5V...lq81XEw==",
>   "user"=>{"email"=>"teb@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}

The server output indicates the existence of the user (based on a SELECT statement with known email value):

> User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
>   "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "teb@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT",
>   11]] @user: #]>

But when Devise runs the same query immediately after this check statement, it returns "Completed 401 Unauthorized..."

> User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE
>   "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email",
>   "teb@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 14ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)

Here are the routes.rb and user.rb model files:

```
======= routes.rb =======
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get "/" => "users#home"
    devise_for :users
    resources :users do
        resources :posts
    end
end

======= user.rb =======
class User < ApplicationRecord
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    has_many :posts
    has_many :comments
end
```

What could possibly be causing this lack of authorization?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look for your controllers and Application controller with the statements such as `cuurent_user` or `before_action`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :login_required, :only => [:method1,:method2]
    ...
 end
```

could be that the method you are trying to call is listed as requiring authentication, but you are not logged in.

Can you also post an excerpt of your Controller with the methods in it?

Another possible problem is that your route might be defined incorrectly: